# Error creating bean with name 'CommandService' defined in ServletContext

Tags: spring-mvc

> SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener
> instance of class com.thomson.live.wca.web.listener.WCAListener
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'mbeanExporter': Invocation of init method
> failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'CommandService' defined in ServletContext
> resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-config.xml]: Initialization of bean
> failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Failed to obtain
> BeanInfo for class
> [com.thomsonreuters.wlb.news.command.impl.CommandService]; nested
> exception is java.beans.IntrospectionException: type mismatch between
> read and write methods    at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
> at
> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
> at
> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
> at
> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
> at
> com.thomson.live.wca.web.listener.WCAListener.contextInitialized(WCAListener.java:44)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5110)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5633)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1015)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:991)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1127)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:2020)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'CommandService' defined in ServletContext
> resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-config.xml]: Initialization of bean
> failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Failed to obtain
> BeanInfo for class
> [com.thomsonreuters.wlb.news.command.impl.CommandService]; nested
> exception is java.beans.IntrospectionException: type mismatch between
> read and write methods    at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
> at
> org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.autodetect(MBeanExporter.java:880)
> at
> org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.autodetectBeans(MBeanExporter.java:842)
> at
> org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeans(MBeanExporter.java:521)
> at
> org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.afterPropertiesSet(MBeanExporter.java:413)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)

This is my pom.xml file

com.thomson
wca
4.0

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>wca-index-server</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>Index Server</name>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-asm -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>









    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thomson</groupId>
        <artifactId>wca-constants</artifactId>
        <version>${wca.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thomson</groupId>
        <artifactId>common_util</artifactId>
        <version>${wca.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thomson</groupId>
        <artifactId>wca-legacy-normalization</artifactId>
        <version>${wca.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thomson</groupId>
        <artifactId>wca-normal-top-level</artifactId>
        <version>${wca.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thomson</groupId>
        <artifactId>wca-client-old</artifactId>
        <version>${wca.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thomson</groupId>
        <artifactId>wca-client-new</artifactId>
        <version>${wca.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thomson</groupId>
        <artifactId>wca-index-manager</artifactId>
        <version>${wca.version}</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId> <artifactId>wca-api</artifactId> 
        <version>${project.version}</version> <type>test-jar</type> <scope>test</scope> 
        <exclusions> <exclusion> <groupId>commons-vfs</groupId> <artifactId>commons-vfs</artifactId> 
        </exclusion> </exclusions> </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>${oracle.client.artifact}</artifactId>
        <version>${oracle.client.version}</version>
        <scope>${oracle.client.scope}</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javaee-glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-glassfish</artifactId>
        <version>5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>

    <finalName>wca</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <!-- Adding tomcat 7 plugin to run the project within eclipse and local -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <path>/</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.6</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2-beta-2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>attached</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly-1.1.0-index-server-deploy-package.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>


<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>jetty-wrap</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                        <tmpDir>${jetty.tmpDir}</tmpDir>
                        <contextPath>/wca</contextPath>
                        <stopKey>naynowtuwunow</stopKey>
                        <stopPort>9998</stopPort>

                        <requestLog
                            implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.NCSARequestLog">
                            <filename>target/yyyy_mm_dd.request.log</filename>
                            <retainDays>90</retainDays>
                            <append>true</append>
                            <extended>false</extended>
                            <logTimeZone>GMT</logTimeZone>
                        </requestLog>
                        <systemProperties>
                            <systemProperty>
                                <name>base.directory</name>
                                <value>${basedir}</value>
                            </systemProperty>
                            <systemProperty>
                                <name>env</name>
                                <value>${env}</value>
                            </systemProperty>


                            <systemProperty>
                                <name>com.sun.management.jmxremote</name>
                                <value></value>
                            </systemProperty>
                            <systemProperty>
                                <name>com.sun.management.jmxremote.port</name>
                                <value>9876</value>
                            </systemProperty>
                            <systemProperty>
                                <name>com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl</name>
                                <value>false</value>
                            </systemProperty>
                            <systemProperty>
                                <name>com.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate</name>
                                <value>false</value>
                            </systemProperty>

                            <systemProperty>
                                <name>app.home</name>
                                <value>d:/wca</value>
                            </systemProperty>
                            <systemProperty>
                                <name>app.log.dir</name>
                                <value>target/logs/IndexClient</value>
                            </systemProperty>
                            <systemProperty>
                                <name>app.comp</name>
                                <value>IndexClient</value>
                            </systemProperty>
                            <systemProperty>
                                <name>app.env</name>
                                <value>${env}</value>
                            </systemProperty>

                            <systemProperty>
                                <name>com.mchange.v2.c3p0.management.ManagementCoordinator</name>
                                <value>com.mchange.v2.c3p0.management.NullManagementCoordinator</value>
                            </systemProperty>

                            <systemProperty>
                                <name>jetty.port</name>
                                <value>9090</value>
                            </systemProperty>
                        </systemProperties>


                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                            <artifactId>geronimo-j2ee_1.4_spec</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0</version>
                            <scope>provided</scope>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>

                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>start-jetty</id>
                            <phase>test-compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>deploy-war</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                                <daemon>true</daemon>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>stop-jetty</id>
                            <phase>test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>stop</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>


                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

    </profile>
</profiles>



<reporting>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
                <xmlOutputDirectory>
                    ${project.build.directory}/findbugs-reports
                </xmlOutputDirectory>
                <threshold>high</threshold>
                <effort>Max</effort>
                <excludeFilterFile>findbugs-exclude.xml</excludeFilterFile>
                <includeFilterFile>findbugs-include.xml</includeFilterFile>
                <!-- <visitors> -->
                <!-- FindDeadLocalStores,UnreadFields,FindUncalledPrivateMethods, SQL_BAD_RESULTSET_ACCESS -->
                <!-- </visitors> -->
                <!-- <omitVisitors> -->
                <!-- FindDeadLocalStores,UnreadFields -->
                <!-- </omitVisitors> -->
                <onlyAnalyze>com.thomson.*</onlyAnalyze>
                <!-- <pluginList>/libs/fb-contrib/fb-contrib-2.8.0.jar</pluginList> -->
                <debug>true</debug>
                <relaxed>true</relaxed>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <targetJdk>1.6</targetJdk>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</reporting>

<properties>
    <jetty.daemon.mode>false</jetty.daemon.mode>
</properties>
```

Comment: can you provide us more context? e.g. your pom?

Comment: I have updated pom.xml file please check and tell me solution